# How to convert pandas series element into string

Tags: python, pandas, pymongo

I have a pandas dataframe in which I have mongoDB's objectIDs stored. I want to fetch new documents from mongoDB, for this I am using last document ObjectId stored in pandas dataframe. But when I query the database it gives me an error.

Here is what I am doing.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(db.dataset2.find()))

last_inserted_id = (df['_id'].tail(1))

for i in db.dataset2.find({"_id": {"$gt": ObjectId(last_inserted_id) }}):
     print i
```

Then it gives me an error..

```
TypeError: id must be an instance of (str, unicode, ObjectId), not <class      
'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

This is how my dataframe looks like..

```
   _id  \
0  5663110c691db01e0cac9d89   
1  56631205691db01e0cac9d8a   

                   dish                                order_area order_id  
0  [{u'dish_substitute': u'Yes', u'home_chef_name...        NaN  order_1   
1  [{u'dish_substitute': u'Yes', u'home_chef_name...        NaN  order_2   

 order_lat     order_long              order_time user_id  
0  73.955741   40.772027 2015-12-05 16:30:04.345  user_1  
1  43.955741   70.772027 2015-12-05 16:34:13.281  user_2
```

How to deal with this?
please help..

Comment: I think you can convert last item to list and from list to string - `last_inserted_id =  "".join(df['_id'].tail(1).tolist())`, if `df['_id'].dtypes`  is `object` - what can be `string`.

Comment: If it is numeric, you can try: `last_inserted_id =  "".join(df['_id'].astype('str').tail(1).tolist())`. Btw, I post comments, because I dont know your input dataframe.

Comment: could you show part of you dataframe?

Answer (score 1):

```
print df
#                        _id  no
#0  5663110c691db01e0cac9d89  55
#1  56631205691db01e0cac9d8a  77

#convert to string approach
last_inserted_id = "".join(df['_id'].astype('str').tail(1).tolist())
print last_inserted_id
#56631205691db01e0cac9d8a


#tail only approach
last_inserted_id =  "".join(df['_id'].tail(1))
print last_inserted_id
#56631205691db01e0cac9d8a

#iloc approach
last_inserted_id_iloc =  df['_id'].iloc[-1]
print last_inserted_id_iloc 
#56631205691db01e0cac9d8a
```

Comment: When I do what most of people said.. `last_inserted_id = df_imported['_id'].tail(1).tolist()

str2 = ''.join(last_inserted_id)`    it gives me an error `TypeError: sequence item 0: expected string, ObjectId found`    I am new to python really do not know whats going on here..

Comment: I have added my dataframe. please help

Comment: _id is the id column (First column in a dataframe)

Comment: `last_inserted_id = "".join(df_imported['_id'].astype('str').tail(1).tolist())
`   This has worked finally.. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: Sorry for that.. didn't know of it.. I have accepted your previous answer but, I don't know how to accept it in comment.